# no top-level method 'ThemeData.fallback' declared ,flutter

Tags: visual-studio-code, dart, flutter

i'm trying to run the flutter documentation code example , but i keep getting this error

> NoSuchMethodError : No top-level method 'ThemeData.fallback' declared.
>   Receiver: Top-level Tried Calling : ThemeData.fallback

and this is the code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a stack trace to go with the error? What version of Flutter are you using?

Comment: there is no stack trace , and i'm using the latest version (downloaded from the official site )

Comment: Do you still have this issue on the latest version? If so, does the error only occur when running, or does it show in the Problems window too?

Comment: i had this issue , but it was fixed by reinstalling the flutter sdk

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a few errors like this when people have inadvertently modified the Flutter SDK (a bug in older versions would allow quick-fixes to make edits to the SDK). There's an issue about detecting this better here:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25220

You can use git to clean the SDK repo, or re-download/extract the SDK.

Comment: it's an old error , reinstalling flutter fixed it but thanks !